# Select rows from multiple tables with common fields in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table as follows:

create table table1(id integer,firstname text,lastname text);

#### id firstname lastname

====================
1 ben   taylor
2 rob   taylor
3 rob   smith
4 rob   zombie
5 peter smith
6 ben smith
7 peter   taylor

Now I have another table create table table2(id integer,position integer);

#### id position

===========
1 5
1 9
2 6
3 7
6 2

I want to select rows with a lastname , where the lastname must be shared by ben and rob and firstnames must be ben and rob.
Now I also want the position of ben to be one lesser than that of rob, hence the result would be :

#### id firstname lastname position

===========================
1 ben   taylor 5
2 rob   taylor 6

What should the sql query be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the last name:

```
select lastname
from names n join
     position p
     on n.id = p.id
where firstname in ('ben', 'rob')
group by lastname
having count(distinct firstname) = 2 and
       1+max(case when firstname = 'ben' then p.position end) = max(case when firstname = 'rob' then p.position end)
```

You can then get the original list with:

```
select n.*, p.position
from names n join
     position p
     on n.id = p.id
where firstname in ('ben', 'rob') and
      lastname in (select lastname
                   from names n join
                        position p
                        on n.id = p.id
                   where firstname in ('ben', 'rob')
                   group by lastname
                   having count(distinct firstname) = 2 and
                          1+max(case when firstname = 'ben' then p.position end) = max(case when firstname = 'rob' then p.position end)
                  )
```

I think the following query answers your question, with the caveat that this combines the names into one row:

```
select nben.*, p.position, nrob.*, prob.position
from names nben join
     positions p
     on nben.id = p.id and
        nben.firstname = 'ben' join
     names nrob
     on nrob.firstname = 'rob' and
        nrob.lastname = nben.lastname join
     positions prob
     on nrob.id = prob.id and
        p.position = prob.position - 1
```

Also, this is untested.

Comment: This query outputs all three `taylor`s, and the `smith`s.

Comment: the result i am looking for is written at the end of the question.

Comment: Sorry about that . . . I totally missed the condition on positions.  I put in one fix for that, assuming there is only one position per name.

Comment: This doesn't output anything.

Comment: there can be many positions per name as in example ben taylor is at position 5 and 9,but ben taylor at position 5 is in the result

Comment: your solution  1+max(case when firstname = 'ben' then p.position end) = max(case when firstname = 'rob' then p.position end)  does not seem to work and i could not understand this line to make it work.

Comment: In the two of your solutions i edited below which one is more efficient and suitable if the size of the tables are big with size in several gigabytes?

Comment: That's a lot of data.  I would be inclined to find the "ben" and "rob" ids first, then dispense with the joins to the names table.  But the version with the join is the one that generally works.  The other makes some conditions on the data.

Answer (score 0):

This gives me the result i needed obtained from Gordon Linoff's solution:
select * from(select n.*, p.position
from names n join
     position p
     on n.id = p.id
where firstname in ('ben', 'rob') and
      lastname in (select lastname
                   from names n join
                        position p
                        on n.id = p.id
                   where firstname in ('ben', 'rob')
                   group by lastname
                   having count(distinct firstname) = 2

```
              )
         )
```

as x,names,position 
where 
(x.id!=names.id and names.id=position.id and names.lastname=x.lastname 
and (x.firstname='rob' and names.firstname='ben') and x.position=position.position+1)
or 
(x.id!=names.id and names.id=position.id and names.lastname=x.lastname
 
and (x.firstname='ben' and names.firstname='rob') and x.position+1=position.position)

Answer (score -1):

Gordon Linoff's solutions:
select nben.*, p.position
from names nben join
     positions p
     on nben.id = p.id and
        nben.firstname = 'ben' join
     names nrob
     on nrob.firstname = 'rob' and
        nrob.lastname = nben.lastname join
     positions prob
     on nrob.id = prob.id and
        p.position = prob.position - 1
gives same result as:

select * from(select n.*, p.position
from names n join
position p
on n.id = p.id
where firstname in ('ben', 'rob') and
lastname in (select lastname
from names n join
position p
on n.id = p.id
where firstname in ('ben', 'rob')
group by lastname
having count(distinct firstname) = 2

```
          )
     )
```

as x,names,position 
where (x.id!=names.id and names.id=position.id 
and names.lastname=x.lastname 
and (x.firstname='ben' and names.firstname='rob') 
and x.position+1=position.position)

Comment: In the two of Gordon Linoff's solutions i edited, which one is more efficient and suitable if the size of the tables are big with size in several gigabytes?